# How can I use loc to slice dataframes by date, when df.index is type datetimeindex?

Tags: pandas, dataframe, datetime, indexing, timestamp

[image: df_uci17.head()][image: df_uci17 is non-null, index is type datetimeindex. When I use loc it returns an empty dataframe and when I use iloc I have an issue of class mismatching]

[image: error from iloc]
I'm trying to slice this df_uci17/18 dataframe and whenever I use loc it just returns an empty dataframe. If I use iloc I have an issue with class timestamp/string/wtv indexers dealing with datetimeindex, which is the class of the df_uci17/18 index.

Comment: we need to see what `df_uci17` looks like

Comment: its basically the same as df_uci18 but for 2017, DatetimeIndex, dates converted to datetime with '/' replaced by '-', errors=coerse

Comment: try boolean indexing: `df[(df.index >= then1) & (df.index <= then2)]`

Comment: I get `Invalid comparison between dtype=datetime64[ns] and date`

Comment: convert `then1` and `then2` to `datetime64[ns]`

Comment: and if I cut the ".date()" off, I get `operands could not be broadcast together with shapes`

Comment: can you copy and paste your code into the question and not the images

Comment: Had an mistake spelling the boolean indexing, it's now working fine. One of those pains. THANK YOU SO MUCH CHRIS, I was trying to do this for 5 days now